# disk usage + dialog = graphic interface for disk usage vs disk capacity?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, disk, dialog

I wonder if it is possible to use `dialog` gauge option to create a graphic displaying the percentage of disk used vs disk capacity? And if so, how could I do it?

Generically speaking, how can I use `dialog` to compare between two different values?

Comment: Tell us more about dialog: What is it?

Comment: Citing the below mentioned webpage, dialog is " a program that will let you to present a variety of questions or display messages using dialog boxes from a shell script. These types of dialog boxes are implemented (though not all are necessarily compiled into dialog):

calendar, checklist, dselect, editbox, form, fselect, gauge, infobox, inputbox, inputmenu, menu, mixedform, mixedgauge, msgbox (message), passwordbox, passwordform, pause, progressbox, radiolist, tailbox, tailboxbg, textbox, timebox, and yesno (yes/no)."

https://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at `ncdu`, if you want or need a disk-usage utility with a textual user interface. It's based on ncurses, which is what dialog is based on as well.  By default, it shows a column, which can be toggled (g), with a graphical representation of the size of the various files and directories.

https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/

If you are trying to write a program, however, then show what you've tried and ask for help here or on stackoverflow.